# PDO Insert uploading a textarea into my DB

Tags: php, pdo, textarea, uploading

I have been trying for months to figure out how to fix and create what I am envisioning which I know is possible to be done and probably is not hard to do.

I am trying to take a textarea that I have placed on a page of mine upload its contents into a database where people can view the information they uploaded. Here's an example.

Person A copy/pastes text into a text area at: http://example.com/textarea/
he clicks an upload/submit button and gets a link like this: http://example.com/A93KJUQ21.txt
Anyone that has access to that link will be able to click it and it will display the contents that were uploaded to it. Whatever Person A, B, C, D, etc uploads it will generate a new unique link to the information. Example of this would be as follows:

http ://example.com/A93KJUQ21.txt

http ://example.com/JKO2QN498.txt

http ://example.com/PMNR01NEQ.txt

and so on..

Here is the code I currently have

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
$textarea = $_POST['paste-area'];

//Add validations

$odb = new PDO("mysql:dbname=dbname;host=localhost", "dbusername", 
"mypasswordgoeshere");

$query = $odb->prepare("INSERT INTO submission (`textarea`) VALUES 
(:textarea)"); //I'm just making up the structures

$query->bindParam(':textarea', $textarea, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$status = $query->execute(); //$status contains true or false

//Other codes...
}
}

?>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Take a look at this: [link](https://davidwalsh.name/basic-php-file-handling-create-open-read-write-append-close-delete) You can create new files and put contents from textarea inside the file created. You can give your file an unique name by generating some random string. Voting to close

Answer (score 0):

Your table needs two columns, the random string and the `textarea` contents. When the user submits the form, you need to create the random string and insert that into the DB along with the text area.

```
$string = uniqid();
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO submission (id, textarea) VALUES (:string, :textarea)");
$query->bindParam(':string', $string);
$query->bindParam(':textarea', $textarea);
$query->execute();
echo "Link is <a href='http://example.com/lookup.php?id=$string'>href='http://example.com/lookup.php?id=$string</a>";
```

I've made the link point to a PHP script. You can't retrieve from the database using a `.txt` URL, that just tries to download a regular file. You need to point to a PHP script that fetches the textarea from the `submission` table.

If you want to make it seem like a `.txt` file, you could use a rewrite rule on the server, that rewrites the `.txt` URL to the equivalent `.php` URL.

Comment: An example site for something I want to do is http://hastebin.com/

I don't want to do all that save stuff, but only want the information to be displayed using a unique link.

Comment: They're probably using a rewrite rule.

Answer (score -1):

why do you think you need a database for this?

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['text'])) {
    $filename = uniqid().".txt";
    file_put_contents($filename, $_POST['text']);
    die("http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/$filename");
}
?>
<form method=post>
<textarea name=text></textarea>
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

Comment: That code worked to create a unique filename with the extension ".txt", but I still have no way to add the textareas contents to the database.

Comment: Well no wonder you spent months for this trifle task, if a code that works for everyone doesn't work for you :)

Comment: What do you mean? I said the code worked but it only is giving me a unique link after hitting a submit button. It is not displaying the contents of what I entered into the textarea when I follow the link it gives.